# Jump scanf ,i cant use multiple scanf

Tags: c

this is my code :

```
int x, y, z,n;
printf("Introduceti minimul de cifere,vocale,consoane pe care trebuie sa le contina un cuvant\nSub forma x\\y\\z\n");



scanf("%d\%d\%d", &x, &y, &z);
   printf("Introduceti numarul pe care il doriti de cuv asemanatoare\n");
            scanf(" %d", &n);
```

This program doesn't read  `n`.

Comment: `\%` is an unknown escape sequence - invalid standard C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't separate your numbers entered by a backslash in this manner...

```
scanf("%d\%d\%d", &x, &y, &z);
```

...because what the compiler sees is you escaping the %. To put a backslash into a string you need to double it up like this

```
scanf("%d\\%d\\%d", &x, &y, &z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do this:

```
printf("\\\n");
```

Comment: @Krasnyy: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Beware, a backslash in a format string must be escaped. The first scanf (`scanf("%d\%d\%d", &x, &y, &z);`) expects one single integer **followed with %d%d**. So it only read one single value into `x`. You need:

```
int x, y, z,n;

printf("Introduceti minimul de cifere,vocale,consoane pe care trebuie sa le contina un cuvant\nSub forma x\\y\\z\n");
if (3 != scanf("%d\\%d\\%d", &x, &y, &z)) {
    // process error
    ...
}
printf("Introduceti numarul pe care il doriti de cuv asemanatoare\n");
if (1 != scanf(" %d", &n)) {
    // process error
    ...
}
```

What you should have learned from that: **ALWAYS TEST RETURN VALUE OF INPUT FUNCTIONS**